# Nodejs : Return stdout

Tags: node.js

I am trying to return username using this simple function , but its not working .I thing its  asynchronous thats why it returns `undefined` . So what is the best way to return value from `stdout` ?

```
function User() {
    exec('whoami',function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            return stdout;
        });
}
```

There is a node module [execSync](https://github.com/mgutz/execSync) , but its not for production machine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following,

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function User(cmd, callback) {
    exec(cmd, function (error, stdout) {
        return callback(null, stdout);
    });
}

User('whoami', function(err, callback){
    console.log(callback);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a value from an asynchronous callback, which has no effect. You need to pass a callback to `User()` instead:

```
function User(cb) {
  exec('whoami',function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error)
      return cb(error);
    cb(null, stdout);
  });
}
```